# Copy the whole file from disk to memory to process or read data from file each time i need until the file is all read

Tags: c++, c, memory-efficient

I am working on something that cares efficiency very much. There are thousands of files and each file is as large as 300M. Each file contains at least 500 thousand items. My work is to process each item as quick as possible. The physical memory size is not an issue. So. will I benefit from copying the whole file into the memory and get each item from the memory instead of get each item from the disk ? And are there any other methods that can save time in IO process? Thank you!

Comment: You should tell us a bit more about your application, and what did you tried so far, perhaps showing some code.

Comment: If you do a single linear scan through the file, then you shouldn't have to worry much. Disks and filesystems are usually quite well optimized for that access pattern. For more complicated access patterns, memory mapping might be better, but then I/O libraries might already do that internally (IIRC, the BSD `stdio` library does that).

Comment: well, my work is actually to process the cap files captured by wireshark in Windows. The disk type is not SSD so far as I know. I read each item in the cap file one by one.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [mmap(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html), [madvise(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/madvise.2.html), [posix_fadvise(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html), and [readahead(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/readahead.2.html) syscalls (notice that `readahead` is Linux specific and blocking, you might want to call it in advance, or in a separate thread).

You might perhaps not care that much: just reading in advance each 200Mb file, a few seconds before processing it, might be enough. The kernel file system and disk cache is doing a lot; with a lot of RAM data would be in memory already.

And you didn't tell us if your program is a single long-lasting process, or if you drive it thru some repetitive script invoking the same program on each big file.

System configuration and hardware does matter a lot. You could configure the file system (at `mke2fs` time) with large blocks (e.g. 16Kb or 64Kb). If you can afford them, SSD disks would bring a lot.

You could also design your application to carefully use some cleverly setup database.

Answer (score 2):

For starters:

```
std::vector<char> input;
std::ifstream file("filename.txt")'
// maybe find file size and do a reserve on input
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<char>(file), std::istream_iterator<char>()
          std::back_inserter(input));
```

If this actually ends up being not fast enough for you, memory mapped
files are usually reduce a lot of the IO overhead.

The [Boost.Iostream](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/mapped_file.html) library provides portable memory mapped files with
a modern interface and is really fast.

Anyway: Try the easy solution first, structure your program to separate the file IO process from the parser and actual processing, then optimize the parts that are actually expensive. Such a program structure will also allow for easy to implement producer/consumer parallelism.

An important part is also what your `items` are. Can they be directly mapped into a `struct` or do they have to be processed. If so, how complicated is the actual parsing?